# Comparar fechas por mes especifico en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datetime, carbon

Estoy midiendo la cantidad de productos producidos en un mes con google chart.

Para esto en cada producto guardo su fecha de realizacion, ejemplo  2019-02-11. Quiero filtrar todos los productos producidos en el mes actual comparandola con la fecha actual del servidor mediante carbon, pero pregunto ¿como puedo comparar 2019-02-11 VS 2019-02-13 cuando no puedo obtener el mes  de forma limpia, sabiendo que ambas variables podrian tener dias diferentes y eso haria que no coincidieran con un condicional if.

```
 $date = Carbon::now();
$date = $date->format('Y/m/d');

$empleados = User::with('tareas')->get();

dd(now()->toDateString());
```

**FECHA IMPRESA CON NOW()** = "2019-02-12"

**FECHA OBTENIDA EN LA CONSULTA** = 2019/2/10

Comment: Lo acabo de agregar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes asegurarte que el campo sea tipo date o datetime o similar e indicarle esto al modelo en Laravel, para que pueda ser convertido automáticamente a una instancia de Carbon.

En el modelo utiliza la propiedad dates:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'fecha_inicio',
];
```

Y de ser necesario, utiliza la propiedad casts para darle formato:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'fecha_inicio' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

---

Por lo que veo usas Carbon, entonces podrías hacer algo así para comparar los dos meses, usando la propiedad month de la instancia de Carbon:

```
if ($product->created_at->month == now()->month) {
    // mes coincide...
}
```

Más información: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

---

También puedes usar:

```
$product->created_at->isSameMonth(now());
```

O mejor aún:

```
$product->created_at->isCurrentMonth();
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Comment: cuando hago esto $tarea->created_at->month me da error,  si hago esto dd( $tarea->created_at->month) deberia ver el mes no?

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: Trying to get property 'month' of non-object

Comment: $empleados[0]->tareas[0]->fecha_inicio->month  Este es el campo real que estoy consultando lo cambie en la base de datos a typo date, ya que estaba en varchar

Comment: Revisa la edición que hice.